# Animation jumpyness with input padding and jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery, animation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-1.9

So I've tested this with just pure jQuery and it works fine. It has something to do with the bootstrap CSS. I am trying to do a simple width animation, and it works, however the animation "jumps". Take a look at the fiddle to see what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/qVz9M/2/

You can see without the bootstrap CSS it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/qVz9M/4/

HTML:

```
<input class="input-small find" type="text" >
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".find").focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "200px"
    }, 500);
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: "90px"
    }, 500);
});
```

Edit:

So it seems the PADDING is the problem. Anyone else experiencing this?

Edit2: This is a bug in jQuery with a fix release of 1.9.1

Comment: The animation is smooth for me on Mac Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I'm on windows 7 - can anyone else confirm this is happening on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiousity, is the animation any smoother for you if it uses CSS animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/yYYJE/ ?

CSS

```
input.find{
width:90px;
transition: all .5s;
-moz-transition:all .5s; /* Firefox 4 */; 
-webkit-transition: all .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all .5s; /* Opera */
}
input.find:focus{
width:200px; 

}
```

Comment: Yes it is - I would use that, but I have to be compatible with IE8